# How can i get link when i click on button and stored in session variable

Tags: javascript, php, session

I have foreach loop which when looping outputs the items held in an array.This works great, but I want to store a few things per EACH item in session variables so I can use this information elsewhere without page refresh,I am trying to create session variables inside the foreach loop,but of course the variables need to have different data every time it loops through a different item.Suppose in below code i have three different product link,when i click on button how do i get that particular link for that particular product is stored in session variable without reloading a page.When i redirect from one page to other i used that link which is in session variable using session concept.

**session.php**

```
<?php
$a=array(
    array("Htc 526 black","htc.jpg",23000,"http://www.flipkart.com"),
    array("Iphone 6s","apple.jpg",43000,"http://www.amazon.com"),
    array("Sony xperia c3 dual","sony.jpg",19000,"http://www.snapdeal.com")
);

foreach($a as $value)
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['link']=$value[3];
?>
<script>
    function redirect()
    {
        window.location="redirection.php";
    }
</script>
<button onclick="redirect();">Click Me</button>

<?php
}
?>
```

**redirection.php**

```
<?php
if(session_id()=="")
{
    session_start();
}
$deep_link=$_SESSION['link'];
echo $deep_link;?>
```

My query is when i redirect from one page to other and when i echo the session variable(product link),it only echo's the last value Instead it takes that particular product links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array assign has only one room ,so create increase number for multiple array like this.
// two parameter making style

```
<?php
$i = 0; //init number for ++
$a=array(
array("Htc 526 black","htc.jpg",23000,"http://www.flipkart.com"),
array("Iphone 6s","apple.jpg",43000,"http://www.amazon.com"),
array("Sony xperia c3 dual","sony.jpg",19000,"http://www.snapdeal.com")
);

foreach($a as $value)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['link'][$i]=$value[3];    
?>
<script>
function redirect(i,phone)
{
    window.location="redirection.php?d="+i+"&pno="+phone;   //can use one more parameter like this ...
}
</script>
<button onclick="redirect(<?= $i ?>,'<?= $value[0]; ?>');">Click Me</button> //can add parameter by ',' as you want
 //eg link structure =><button onclick="redirect(1,'Htc 526 black');">Click Me</button>
<?php
$i++;  //increase array number
}
?>
```

then you should call in redirection.php

```
<?php
if(session_id()=="")
{
session_start();
}
$i = $_GET['d'];
$p = $_GET['pno'];//call by parameter name
$deep_link=$_SESSION['link'][$i];
echo $deep_link."</br>".$p;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support, when i execute a code it gives three button and in the above case when i click on any of three button it will redirect and show me all the three links instead i should only show when i click on first button it give http://www.flipkart.com only , click on second button it give http://www.amazon.com and when i click on 3rd button it give http://www.snapdeal.com, So how can i get link on button click and store in session variable before redirect to the redirection.php page

Comment: it works that i wan't, the no. of array records may change (i.e. 3 records in above). So what can i take $_SESSION['link'][$i]=$value[3]; instead of $value[3];

Comment: By using above just tell me how can i pass more than two parameters(in above case we pass "i" only)

Comment: i am waiting for your reply